# Is `auto` specifier slower in compilation time?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, auto, compile-time

Since C++11 we can use `auto a = 1+2` instead of `int a = 1+2` and the compiler deduces the type of `a` by itself. How does it work? Is it slower during compile time (more operations) than declaring the type myself?

Comment: Have you tried measuring codes with and without `auto`?
Related: http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: This is a compile-type specifier, it does not affect the running time.

Comment: I meant slower compile time

Comment: @CIsForCookies: That depends on your compiler!

Comment: I doubt it would amount to much, to be honest, because the compiler has to deduce the "ideal" expression type anyways to make sure it is compatible with the *declared type*. So I would imagine implementing *auto* likely builds on a lot of what the compiler is doing already.

Comment: Considering how _extremely_ common integers are, and their role in Integer Constant Expressions, I wouldn't be surprised if compilers had separate paths for "integral expressions" and "every other type of expression".

Comment: `auto` is only legal where the type can be inferred from an expression, and the compiler must determine the expression's type anyway to validate whether the assignment (to non-`auto`) is valid. **On the other hand**, using `auto` implies that no implicit conversions take place, nor does the compiler need to validate whether narrowing conversions etc. happen. Thus, `auto` may very well _compile faster_. It might even be faster at runtime, in some odd cases (where conversions are otherwise made due to the programmer's choice of type).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`auto` is asking the C++11 *compiler* to make some *limited* kind of [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) (look into [Ocaml](http://ocaml.org/) if you want some more sexy type inference language). But the overhead is compile-time only.

If you replace `auto a=1+2;` with `int a=1+2;` (both have the same meaning, see [answer by simplicis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32519417/841108)) and if you ask your compiler to [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (and probably even without asking for optimizations) you'll probably get the same [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32413422/841108).

If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) try to compile a small C++11 `foo.cc` file with `g++ -Wall -fverbose-asm -O -S foo.cc` and look (with an editor) into the generated `foo.s` assembler file. You'll see no difference in the generated code (but the assembler file might perhaps change slightly, e.g. because of metadata like debug information etc.)

If you are concerned about *slower compile-time* I guess that using `auto` is not a decisive factor (probably, overloading could be more costly in compilation time). C++11 is nearly designed to practically *require* a lot of [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (in particular sophisticated inlining and constant folding and dead code elimination), and its "parsing" (notably header inclusion and template expansion) is costly.

[Precompiling headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12438040/841108) and parallel builds with `make -j` (and perhaps [`ccache`](https://ccache.samba.org/) or `distcc`) might help in improving the overall compilation time, much more than avoiding `auto`.

And if you wanted to systematically avoid `auto`  (in particular in [range-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loops like `std::map<std::string,int> dict; for (auto it: dict) {`...`}`) you'll end up typing much more source code (whose parsing and checking takes significant time) with more risks of error. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32510343/841108), you might guess slightly wrongly the type, and expliciting it (slightly wrongly) might slow down the execution of your code because of additional conversions.

If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you might pass the [`-ftime-report`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) to `g++` and get time measurements about various GCC passes and phases.

Comment: What has `auto` to do with compiler optimisations? The meaning of `auto` is prescribed by the language, and `auto a = 1 + 2;` means exactly the same as `int a = 1 + 2;`.

Comment: Indeed, so what? A C++ compiler *practically* needs to optimize a lot.

Comment: Yes,. but that seems unrelated to the topic of this question.

Comment: By the way, placeholder types (and templates/values) are getting polished with Concepts, so I wouldn't refer to OCaml for sexy type inference, but to  [N4377](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf).

Comment: Well, I still find Ocaml's type inference more sexy. It is a matter of taste.

Comment: The compiler already knows the type of the RHS. `auto` simply make the type of the LHS be that type. Without hard evidence, I'm highly skeptical using `auto` is slower. But even if it is, you'd probably need _many_ `auto` declarations for it even to accumulate to make any significant difference. The compiler optimizes either way, so optimizations are irrelevant.

Answer (score 9):

The compiler *knows* the type an expression (like `1 + 2`) evaluates to. That's just the way the language works -- both operands are of type `int` so the result is `int` as well. With `auto a`, you are just telling the compiler to "use the type of the initializing expression".

The compiler does not have to do any additional work or deducing here. The `auto` keyword is merely relieving *you* from figuring out the expression and writing the correct type. (Which you might get wrong, with probably unintended side-effects -- see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510183) (and the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32510343/841108)) for an example how `auto` can avoid unintended run-time conversions and copying.

---

The `auto` keyword really comes into its own with iterators:

```
std::vector< std::string >::const_iterator it = foo.cbegin();
```

versus

```
auto it = foo.cbegin();
```

Answer (score 7):

### How does it work:

From the *ISO/IEC*:

> ...The auto specifier is a placeholder for a type to be deduced (7.1.6.4). The other simple-type-specifiers specify
>   either a previously-declared user-defined type or one of the fundamental types...

### 7.1.6.4 auto specifier

> 1. The auto type-specifier signifies that the type of a variable being declared shall be deduced from its initializer
>      or that a function declarator shall include a trailing-return-type.
> 2. The auto type-specifier may appear with a function declarator with a trailing-return-type in any
>      context where such a declarator is valid.
> 3. Otherwise, the type of the variable is deduced from its initializer. The name of the variable being declared
>      shall not appear in the initializer expression. This use of auto is allowed when declaring variables in a
>      block, in namespace scope, and in a for-init-statement; auto shall appear as one of the decl-specifiers in the decl-specifier-seq and the decl-specifier-seq shall be followed by one or more initdeclarators, each of which shall have a non-empty initializer...

Example:

```
auto x = 5; // OK: x has type int
const auto *v = &x, u = 6; // OK: v has type const int*, u has type const int
static auto y = 0.0; // OK: y has type double
auto int r; // error: auto is not a storage-class-specifier
```

### Is it faster:

The simple answer is **Yes**, by using it a lot of type conversions could be omitted, however, if not used properly it could become great source of errors.

In one of the interviews from Bjarne Stroustrup, he said that `auto` keyword has resulted in win-win situation for coders and compiler implementers.

Comment: I'm very surprised by this. I imagined auto will take a bit more compile time but will be easier for me to write. If what you say is true, why not use auto all the time? It would not allow uninitialized variables -> less room for error, and it is easier to write and faster

Comment: @CIsForCookies well, probably not all the time, but definitely in all the cases that are allowed. In my opinion, it is a great language feature and one should incorporate it in his "dictionary".